# Geolocation does not work on iphone

Tags: iphone, ssl

I know this is a dumb question, and I know I will get a down vote for sure but... still I really need help.

Before anything, yes I do have https ssl certificate installed and all. My code works perfectly on android, and on any PC browser. It only does not work on iphone, and the issue is that if I access my website url without https it won't work, only if I write the complete url, it will work. If I go to chrome on my PC I only have to write something like mysite.com and it works, if I go to my android mobile phone I only write mysite.com and it works, but if I go to my iphone and I write mysite.com it won't work, I get the "Origin does not have permission to use geolocation service", but if I write the full url, https :// www.mysite.com then it works, or if I write www.mysite.com it works

Does anybody know why this happens? and if there is a solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: check this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/3895884/4831524

Comment: I checked the answer but no luck, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to solve this the hard way, I had to redirect the page with php

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "off"){
$redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: ' . $redirect);
exit();
}
```

Although my website is redirected on the server side

If there are any suggestions about security or a better way to get this done, please, they're very welcome